# Erro desconhecido causado pela biblioteca do videojs

Tags: javascript, html5-video

O script funciona normal, porém o console está dando o seguinte erro:

> '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.
>   video.js:86 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function() {
        var myPlayer = videojs("player", {
            "controls": false,
            "autoplay": true,
            "preload": "auto",
            "width": 750,
            "height": 500
        });
        myPlayer.src({type: "video/mp4", src: '/videos/video.mp4'});
        //;
        var video = document.getElementById("player");
        video.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", "return false;");
        videojs.options.flash.swf = "/swf/video.swf";

        $(' .vjs-control-bar').remove();
        $('#player,#buttonVideo').click(function() {

            if (myPlayer.paused()) {
                myPlayer.play();
                $('#buttonVideo').hide();
            } else {
                myPlayer.pause();
                $('#buttonVideo').show();
            }
        });

    });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <video id="player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" poster="/imagens/loader.gif"></video>
```

[**DOCUMENTAÇÃO DO JSVIDEO**](http://videojs.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, mudando a regra do "autoplay", pois no chrome não estava executando o "autoplay", sem antes completar carregamento no Dom do vídeo:

```
 $(function() {
        var myPlayer = videojs("player", {
            "controls": false,
            "autoplay": false, //tirei o autoplay
            "preload": "auto",
            "width": 750,
            "height": 500
        });
        myPlayer.src({type: "video/mp4", src: '/videos/MarcaTecBan.mp4'});
        if (myPlayer.paused()) {
           //liguei o autoplay
            myPlayer.play();
        }

        var video = document.getElementById("player");
        video.setAttribute("oncontextmenu", "return false;");
        videojs.options.flash.swf = "/swf/video-js.swf";
        $(' .vjs-control-bar').remove();
        $('#player,#buttonVideo').click(function() {

            if (myPlayer.paused()) {
                myPlayer.play();
                $('#buttonVideo').hide();
            } else {
                myPlayer.pause();
                $('#buttonVideo').show();
            }
        });
  });
```